# String.Trim() removes more than need?

Tags: c#, string

I found a ticket in our issue tracker that one of customers report a bug that one texts is incomplete!
We have a text conversion program from one legacy system(IBM AS400) to a modern one.
I tracked it and found an unknown behavior on my code!!

First see this:
[image: bug-full state]

As you see, there is two char before first space (char32), but when i remove `Trim()`,the result is:

[image: bug-free state]

Yes, `Trim()` removes char160 from beginning! What happened that `Trim()` works more than need?
**Note:** both pictures are captured in same test state.

Comment: is char 160 not a space in your encoding? or perhaps you are using the wrong code page?

Comment: it's a right character i know.

Comment: this means that your codepage is wrong, because in cp1256 this character _is_ a whitespace.

Comment: based on your definition and of course cp1256, you're right.
but my program has a MapTable for mapping that i'm right!
:D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

160 is a NBSP (Non-breaking space) and according to the documentation, `Trim` will remove all the whitespace. 160 is classified in Unicode as whitespace.

You might want to call `Trim(' ')` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`Trim()` removes leading and trailing white space characters, and that's excactly [what it is supposed to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx).

char 160 is a non breaking space, which is one of the white space characters it eliminates.

Answer (score 2):

Trim removes all white-space, not just spaces. If char 160 is a whitespace in code page 1256, Trim will remove it.

The following code shows that 32 and 160 are whitespace in codepage 1256:

```
        var chars = new byte[] {32,160,164 };
        var enc=Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
        var str=enc.GetString(chars);
        foreach (var character in str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", character, Char.IsWhiteSpace(character));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Returns:

```
       True
       True
       False
```